# Accordion (collapsible panel stack) in mobile-friendly HTML email

Tags: html, css, email, mobile

I need to send emails to users who primarily check emails on their iOS / Android smartphones. 
The emails have multiple sections, so I want to arrange them in an accordion / collapsible format (similar to Wikipedia for example), so that the user can first see the summary, and then tap on any of the links to read further. 
Is this do-able? Any pointers would extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not doable. HTML email clients do not have HTML5 or JQuery. Basically emails are just text-based. HTML emails are coded like it's 1997. Hard coded with inline styling, no libraries like Javascript etc.